# how to apply pagination to firebase search result in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I want to apply pagination to the search result that I get from firebase.
to be more clear, I don't want to apply pagination to the listview. I want to get the search result upon the pagination not to get more than one-page data from firebase. and show that to the user.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far? If you want to achieve pagination in Flutter with Firestore you can go through [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore) document.

Comment: Implementing pagination in Firestore is quite well covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and in previous [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination). If you're having trouble making it work for your use-case, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Firestore/Firebase isn't the best method to apply searching. Try looking at [searching with Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp)
    .getReference("resources")
    .child(FSeason.key)
    .orderByKey()
    .startAt(id)
    .limit(size)
```

Here, startAt(...) will set the cursor in your database. The order of these data is defined by your orderByKey() function which orders your data alphabetically. Moreover, the limit(...) function defines how many data to retrieve per query.

The id in startAt(id) represents the id of the last retrieved document. So, every time you parse the results from your query, store the last element's id and use that for the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using this package from [vedartm.com]: https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore

```
PaginateFirestore(
//item builder type is compulsory.
  itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshots, index) {
    final data = documentSnapshots[index].data() as Map?;
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
      title: data == null ? Text('Error in data') : Text(data['name']),
      subtitle: Text(documentSnapshots[index].id),
    );
  },
  // orderBy is compulsory to enable pagination
  query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').orderBy('name'),
  //Change types accordingly
  itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
  // to fetch real-time data
  isLive: true,
),
```

Just give it a try.
You can change the `PaginateBuilderType.listView` into `PaginateBuilderType.gridView`